# Scope of PHP variables and include

Tags: php, scope

I have a basic feed setup I'm trying to get working.

I have page getting an array of items from the DB and looping through them. It then includes a template for the item and in the item I want to populate it from each item that is being looped through.

I'm running into a problem where the item is not defined in the item template, just in the page where the template is being included.

I have seen a couple posts that say the scope of the variable should still be accessible in the item template but I'm getting the typical error that the variable is not defined. What am I doing wrong or not understanding here?

Page:

```
<div>
    <?php 
        $items=Feed::getItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            includeTemplate("item.php");
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Template:

```
<div>
    echo $item->title;
</div>
```

Comment: So why has this been voted down three times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is likely the `includeTemplate` function.

With `include`, the scope remains the same (imagine it like you're just copying the code from the file to exactly where the include is), but because you've got a function, you're right - it's changing the scope.

What can you do about this? The easiest way would be to change the function like this:

```
includeTemplate($template, array $vars=[]) {
    extract($vars);
    // .. the rest of the function
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
$items=Feed::getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    includeTemplate("item.php", compact("item"));
}
```

This uses [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), which takes an associative array and turns it into variables, and also uses the opposite function, [compact()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php), which takes a list of variable names, and turns it into an associative array.

Comment: Shouldn't `compact($item)` really be `compact("item")` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Comment: @MatteoTassinari you are correct. It's been a little while since I've used it. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That was it exactly, thanks @Samlev.

For others that might read this I moved everything to a function in the object Feed so that I have $item->addItem() and it works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the current scope, you **CANNOT** include the template using a custom function, as it would change the scope.

So, you could do:

```
include "item.php"; // using built-in include
```

Or better, do not rely on scope, and pass only relevant parameters using your custom function:

```
includeTemplate("item.php", $item);  // passing $item as parameter
```

Comment: I didn't see your response, this was exactly the case, thanks for the help.